# What network mapping tools are available?

Tags: networking, network-monitoring, software-recommendation

What [network mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_mapping) tools are available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the same question at [linuxquestions.org](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/network-mapping-tools-663901/). So maybe that could help.

**Excerpts from the link:**

Question: Does anyone know of any network mapping tools for Linux (Ubuntu 8.04) similar to [The Dude](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/thedude.html)?

Answers:

> **1.** There are several things that might do what you want (I have no
>   knowledge of 'The Dude' apart from the link that you posted, so I've
>   assumed anything that does network mapping might be what you want and
>   posted a few from the first few pages on sourceforge):
>
> - Nagios/Nagvis
> - Mila_Ajax_Map
> - Safe Mapping and Reporting Tool (SMART)
> - Network Scaner
> - NMap Console
> - Oggle Network Mapping and Display Tool
> - Prime
> - CartoReso
> - OpenMapper
> - OSPF network visualizer
> - netfuse
> - Ajax Network Map
> - Network Administration Visualized
> - Advanced Network Topology and Inventory (?) ...
>
> If, however, you want an easy life, you should probably check out the
>   packages that your distro offers. Depending on the repos that you have
>   enabled, you should get a list something like this:
>
> - lanmap
> - netdude
> - netmrg (?)
> - zabbix (?)
>
> Looking at the names, netdude seems an attractive prospect, as the
>   possibility is strong that one of these dudes was inspired by the
>   other, in some way.
>
> **2.** Lanmap is similar to The Dude; it creates a graphical layout of
>   your network.

Also after a little bit of Googling found that *lanmap* has been abandoned but there is a [lanmap2](https://github.com/rflynn/lanmap2).