# Linux network options

Tags: networking

I am new to Linux Ubuntu OS. Previously I used Windows 7. Now I am facing lot of problems with this OS. I couldn't able to access the network system's shared files.

In windows I used the tools >> *Map network option to mapping*.

I made several search in Google, but nothing is clear and understandable.

In *System Settings* >> *Network* >> I couldn't map any thing. Please refer the Question: "[What network mapping tools are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60836/what-network-mapping-tools-are-available)"

In Linux what to use? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you have shared filed from a windows machine.

Try this guide http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-windows-7-shared-folders-ubuntu
or Google windows share from ubuntu.

You should only need to point your file manger to `//{IP of server}/{shared folder}` `//server01/share`

Notice the `\\` from windows is `//` in unix.